Problem extracting content from Google News
News Search: Access Google News and search for news related to "Reajuste Salarial".
Analyzes Relevance: Determines the relevance of news based on keywords.
Check Dates: Checks if the news is within a week.
Analyzes Sentiment
Saves Results: Stores the results in an Excel file.
Currently it brings me, 'Name', 'Title', 'Link', 'Date'...
However, I can't bring the news content, whether based on links or divs;
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

def read_names_from_txt(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        return [line.strip() for line in file if line.strip()]

def determine_relevance(title):
    high_keywords = ['Aumento Salarial', 'Reajuste Salarial', 'aumento salarial', 'reajuste salarial']
    medium_keywords = ['Aumento', 'Reajuste', 'reajuste', 'aumento']
    low_keywords = [
        'Transporte público', 'Tarifa dos ônibus', 'Tarifa de metrô', 'Combustível',
        'Gasolina', 'Diesel', 'Alimentação', 'Supermercado', 'Restaurantes',
        'Preço da comida', 'Inflação', 'Economia doméstica', 'Preços de produtos',
        'Taxas de juros', 'Custos de vida', 'Transporte de carga', 'Pedágios',
        'Passagens aéreas', 'Gastos domésticos', 'Despesas familiares'
    ]
    if any(keyword in title for keyword in high_keywords):
        return 3
    elif any(keyword in title for keyword in medium_keywords):
        return 2
    else:
        return 1

def parse_relative_date(relative_str):
    today = datetime.now()
    if "minuto" in relative_str or "hora" in relative_str:
        return today.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
    elif "dia" in relative_str:
        days_ago = int(relative_str.split()[0])
        date = today - timedelta(days=days_ago)
        return date.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
    else:
        return (today - timedelta(days=365)).strftime("%d/%m/%y")

def parse_date(date_str):
    months = {
        "jan.": "janeiro", "fev.": "fevereiro", "mar.": "março", "abr.": "abril", "mai.": "maio", "jun.": "junho",
        "jul.": "julho", "ago.": "agosto", "set.": "setembro", "out.": "outubro", "nov.": "novembro", "dez.": "dezembro"
    }
    current_year = datetime.now().year
    try:
        if not date_str:
            return (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=365)).strftime("%d/%m/%y")
        for abbr, full in months.items():
            date_str = date_str.replace(abbr, full)
        if len(date_str.split()) == 3:
            date_str += f" de {current_year}"
        date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d de %B de %Y")
        return date_obj.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
    except ValueError:
        return parse_relative_date(date_str)

def is_date_within_range(date_str):
    date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%d/%m/%y")
    one_week_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
    return one_week_ago <= date_obj <= datetime.now()

def verify_research(name, title):
    estados = {
        'Acre': 'AC', 'Alagoas': 'AL', 'Amapá': 'AP', 'Amazonas': 'AM', 'Bahia': 'BA', 'Ceará': 'CE', 
        'Distrito Federal': 'DF', 'Espírito Santo': 'ES', 'Goiás': 'GO', 'Maranhão': 'MA', 
        'Mato Grosso': 'MT', 'Mato Grosso do Sul': 'MS', 'Minas Gerais': 'MG', 'Pará': 'PA', 
        'Paraíba': 'PB', 'Paraná': 'PR', 'Pernambuco': 'PE', 'Piauí': 'PI', 'Rio de Janeiro': 'RJ', 
        'Rio Grande do Norte': 'RN', 'Rio Grande do Sul': 'RS', 'Rondônia': 'RO', 'Roraima': 'RR', 
        'Santa Catarina': 'SC', 'São Paulo': 'SP', 'Sergipe': 'SE', 'Tocantins': 'TO'
    }
    name_lower = name.lower()
    title_lower = title.lower()
    if name_lower in title_lower:
        return 1
    for estado, sigla in estados.items():
        if estado.lower() in name_lower and (estado.lower() in title_lower or sigla.lower() in title_lower):
            return 1
    return 0

def analyze_sentiment_and_adjustment(title):
    high_probability_keywords = ['confirmado', 'anunciado', 'aprovado', 'definido', 'decidido']
    low_probability_keywords = ['possível', 'planejado', 'estudado', 'considerado']
    
    sentiment_scores = analyzer.polarity_scores(title)
    sentiment = sentiment_scores['compound']
    
    if any(keyword in title for keyword in high_probability_keywords):
        adjustment_probability = "Alta"
    elif any(keyword in title for keyword in low_probability_keywords):
        adjustment_probability = "Baixa"
    else:
        adjustment_probability = "Indefinida"

    if sentiment > 0.1:
        sentiment_analysis = "Positivo"
    elif sentiment < -0.1:
        sentiment_analysis = "Negativo"
    else:
        sentiment_analysis = "Neutro"
    
    return sentiment_analysis, adjustment_probability

def scrape_content_from_link(link):
    try:
        response = requests.get(link)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
        content = ' '.join([p.get_text(strip=True) for p in paragraphs])
        return content
    except requests.RequestException as e:
        return ""

def scrape_google_news(base_url, search_query, names, output_file):
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws.append(['Nome', 'Titulo', 'Link', 'Data', 'Relevancia', 'Veracidade da pesquisa', 'Sentimento', 'Probabilidade de Reajuste', 'Conteúdo'])

    for name in names:
        url = f"{base_url}&q={search_query}+{name}"
        try:
            response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False)
            response.raise_for_status()
        except requests.RequestException as e:
            continue

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        news_items = soup.find_all('article', attrs={'class': 'IFHyqb DeXSAc'})

        if not news_items:
            ws.append([name, 'Não há informações ', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''])
            continue

        seen_titles = set()
        for item in news_items:
            title_link = item.find('a', class_='JtKRv')
            date = item.find('time')

            if title_link:
                title = title_link.get_text(strip=True)
                if title in seen_titles:
                    continue
                seen_titles.add(title)
                link = 'https://news.google.com' + title_link['href'].lstrip('.')
                
                if date:
                    news_date = parse_date(date.get_text(strip=True))
                else:
                    continue

                if is_date_within_range(news_date):
                    relevance = determine_relevance(title)
                    veracity = verify_research(name, title)
                    sentiment, adjustment_probability = analyze_sentiment_and_adjustment(title)
                    content = scrape_content_from_link(link)
                    ws.append([name, title, link, news_date, relevance, veracity, sentiment, adjustment_probability, content])
                    ws.cell(row=ws.max_row, column=3).hyperlink = link
                    ws.cell(row=ws.max_row, column=3).font = Font(color="0000FF", underline="single")
                else:
                    continue
            else:
                continue
    wb.save(output_file)

base_url = "https://news.google.com/search?hl=pt-BR&gl=BR&ceid=BR:pt-419"
search_query = "Reajuste%20Salarial%20when%3A7d"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'
}
names = read_names_from_txt("nomes.txt")

scrape_google_news(base_url, search_query, names, 'Resultados do Robô.xlsx')```



